# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback

Tags: java, unirest, mashape

I am trying to use Unirest-Mashape to build java applications.

This is my code:

```
import com.mashape.unirest.http.*;
public class PAskMe
{
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
  {
        HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://montanaflynn-dictionary.p.mashape.com/define?word=irony").
                                                                                header("X-Mashape-Key", "KEY").
                                                                                asJson();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
  }
}
```

When I compile my code, It shows no error. But when I run it, it shows the following runtime error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/concurrent/FutureCallback
at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
at PAskMe.PAskMe.main(PAskMe.java:14)
at PAskMe.__SHELL0.run(__SHELL0.java:6)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at bluej.runtime.ExecServer$3.run(ExecServer.java:725)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.concurrent.FutureCallback
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
... 8 more
```

I have included these jars in my project :

[image: I have included these jars in my project]

But still I am getting the error. Please help me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Download `httpcore-4.2.3.jar` and add it to your classpath.

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh wich version of `httpcore.jar` do you use?

Comment: The file name is **httpcore-4.0-alpha6.jar**

Comment: @PriydarshiSingh Try to use version `4.3.3` instead

Answer (score 1):

a .jar file is missing httpcore-4.2.3.jar

download from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0-alpha6

Answer (score 0):

Along with httpcore-4.4.12.jar you also need to add below dependencies to avoid runtime error

httpclient-4.5.6.jar

httpmime-4.5.6.jar

also make sure that all dependencies are compatible with each other